# SQL Server Parse Key Value from text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

i am a novice programmer in sql.

I want to grab some key value pairs from the text in sql column

e.g.

```
some text[Key1=Val1]some text[Key2=Val2][Key3=Val3]some text
```

i want a function which takes Keyname as input & returns the value related with it if found.

```
GetValueFmKey('Key1')
```

should return `Val1` and like on.

Note: the specified values are in text it may have pre or post text exists.

Comment: Well don't. Store different data items in different tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. The square brackets [] are included as part of the text
2. You can use a stored procedure (not sure if you mean SQL Function or a subroutine, i.e. stored proc.

Place the following code in a stored procedure.
Have it's parameter use my @Param and remove the @Param declaration and SET value

```
DECLARE @Param VARCHAR(255) --Remove this
SET @Param = 'Key1'   --Remove this

DECLARE @KeyStart SMALLINT
DECLARE @ValueStart SMALLINT
DECLARE @ValueEnd SMALLINT

SELECT @KeyStart = CHARINDEX(@Param, Col2)
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 = 1;

SET @ValueStart = @KeyStart + LEN(@Param) + 1

SELECT @ValueEnd = CHARINDEX(']', Col2, @KeyStart)
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 = 1;

SELECT SUBSTRING(Col2, @ValueStart, @ValueEnd - @ValueStart)
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetValueFmKey(@text NVARCHAR(1000), @Key NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
AS BEGIN
    SET @key = '['+@key + '='
    IF (CHARINDEX(@Key,@text)=0) RETURN ''
    SET @text = SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX(@Key,@text)+LEN(@Key), LEN(@text))
    RETURN LEFT(@text,CHARINDEX(']',@text)-1)   
END
GO
```

For Example:

```
SELECT dbo.GetValueFmKey('text[Key2=Val2][Key3=Val3]','Key2')
```